# Official way for tower to address all aircraft on frequency for new ATIS?

Tags: air-traffic-control, phraseology

When there's new ATIS info available and the altimiter setting has changed, what's the official phraseology for making the announcement to all the aircraft on the frequency? I'm looking in the FAA ATC phraseology doc FAA order JO 7110.65W, but I don't see it.

My best guess would be something like "Phoenix traffic, information sierra is current, Phoenix altimiter two niner niner eight".

Comment: What makes you think there needs to be specific phraseology for this in the first place, rather than simply the new information superceding the old? (If Sierra is currently being broadcast and a pilot reports having information Romeo, they can be corrected.) If the pilot repeatedly misses the automated ATIS broadcast, what are the odds that they'll hear a single transmission whether manual or automated? I dare say most radio-equipped aircraft have some form of dual-receive capability, whether via dual watch on a single radio or by having two radios for voice communications.

Comment: @user, because most people practicing touch and goes in the pattern aren't going to tune ATIS on the downwind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tower will usually broadcast a note such as “Attention all aircraft: ATIS information Victor is now current. Wind two two zero at seven knots.  Altimeter three zero one four”.  This isn’t official phraseology and really isn’t required of ATC, but is a courtesy call to all pilots operating around the airport to retrieve the latest ATIS broadcast for reference.

Comment: This answer is more-than-partially incorrect. ATC is required to broadcast an advisory when the ATIS changes, as I explain in my answer.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for JO 7110.65 [paragraph 2–9–2**d**](https://www.faa.gov/air_traffic/publications/atpubs/atc_html/chap2_section_9.html#%24paragraph2-9-2). There is no "official" PHRASEOLOGY defined there, but it does specify that controllers need to make a general broadcast which includes an update to pertinent information and provides some examples.

> **d.** Advise aircraft of changes to the ATIS code by broadcasting the change on all appropriate frequencies. The broadcast must include changes to pertinent operational information, when known, that necessitated the ATIS change.
>
> ***EXAMPLE-***
> *“Attention all aircraft, information ALPHA current.”*
> *“Attention all aircraft, information BRAVO current. MICROBURST advisories in effect.”*
> *“Attention all aircraft, information CHARLIE current. Numerous flocks of ducks in the immediate vicinity of (name) airport, altitude unknown.”*
>
> ***NOTE-***
>
> 1. *No additional acknowledgement is required when a controller broadcasts information subsequent to the pilot's initial acknowledgement of the ATIS. [snip]*
> 2. *Pertinent conditions are those that have a clear decisive relevance to the safety of air traffic. As noted in paragraph 2-1-2, Duty Priority, there are many variables involved that make it virtually impossible to develop a standard list... [etc, etc, use best judgment].*

Comment: My technique when broadcasting a "new ATIS" message due to an updated hourly observation, but no other change, is to include the wind and altimeter if I know there is an aircraft on frequency who might not have time to go listen to the new ATIS.

Comment: And we appreciate you doing that!

Answer (score 0):

There have been many occasions when we were monitoring Tower, or Approach, both before and after contacting either, and heard a one time a announcement that the ATIS had been updated, with phraseology as you indicate. I don't recall if the altimeter was included.  Altimeter is given out pretty liberally to anyone contacting Approach/Tower, so you can pick that up if you can determine you are in the same area (have to pay attention, particularly for approach, as they cover a wider area).

Answer (score 0):

The Navy uses the call sign 99 when the transmission applies to all.  “99 information charlie is current.”  I realize this doesn’t apply in the general sense, but it is an example of what you were asking about.